# Unable to import parse in android studio

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am following back4app documentation for intalling parse sdk.Done everything what they said ,but my application class is  unable to import "Parse".I visited old answers regarding this here (stackover flow) but none worked for  me.

my build.gradle(module):--->

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.loginapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:bolts-tasks:1.24.2'
}
```

build.gradle(app):--->

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android manifest:--->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.loginapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    
</application>

</manifest>
```

Application class:--->

```
package com.example.loginapp;
import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {

// Initializes Parse SDK as soon as the application is created
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("fif7ynkG8j1YIhqHywgbHaCgT3rZod0fzMllv8fe")
            .clientKey("wpZd5EqXOPFpxrx5uZYP3dwk38ZTjZWnPODAYThS")
            .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com")
            .build()
    );
}
}
```

please help!

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this dependency:

```
 implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.2"
```